# How to creat xml file with custom tags with colun is node js usig xml2js

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, xml2js

I am trying to create an xml file using xml2js in node js,

```
var obj = {name: "Super", Surname: "Man", age: 23};

var builder = new xml2js.Builder();

var xml = builder.buildObject(obj);
```

With the above code, I got the following xml

```
  <name>Super</name>
  <Surname>Man</Surname>
  <ge>23</age>
```

But how can I get something like this,

```
  <name:loc>Super</name:loc>
  <Surname:loc>Man</Surname:loc>
  <age:loc>23</age:loc>
```

Can anyone suggest me any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Its simple write the keys as string.

```
var xml2js  = require('xml2js')

var obj = {"name:loc": "Super", "Surname:loc": "Man", "age:loc": 23};

var builder = new xml2js.Builder();

var xml = builder.buildObject(obj);

console.log(xml)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it before you go for xml conversion !

```
jsonString = JSON.stringify(obj); //assuming obj is in json format
jsonString = jsonString.replace("\"name\":", "\"name_something\":");
obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

Then do conversion

The logic is, change all element names as required (you may use a for-loop) and then go for making xml